# Prove that $\Delta^{n} f = 0$ i f and only i f $f$ has the form $f ( x ) = a_0(x) + a_1 ( x ) x +. . . + a_{n-1}(x)x^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus

For$f$ a real valued function on the real line, define
the function $\Delta f$ by $\Delta f ( x )= f (x + 1) - f ( x ) $. For $n>1$ , define
recursively by $\Delta^{n} f = \Delta(\Delta^{n-1} f)$. Prove that $\Delta^{n} f = 0$ i f and only i f $f$ has
the form $f ( x ) = a_0(x) + a_1 ( x ) x +. . . + a_{n-1}(x)x^{n-1}$ where $a_0, a_1, . . . , a_{n-1}$
are periodic functions of period ${1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove a stronger version:

**Theorem.** If $\Delta f= b_0(x) + b_1 ( x ) x +. . . + b_{n-1}(x)x^{n-1}$, where $b_0, b_1, . . . , b_{n-1}$  are periodic functions of period $1$, then  $f= a_0(x) + a_1 ( x ) x +. . . + a_{n}(x)x^{n}$, where $a_0, a_1, . . . , a_{n}$  are periodic functions of period $1$.

This can be proved by induction. Note that $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

If $n=1$, then by assumption $\Delta f= b_0(x)$. Hence $$f(x)-f(\{x\})=b_0(x)(x-\{x\}).$$ Hence $a_0(x)=f(\{x\})-b_0(x)\{x\}$ and $a_1(x)=b_0(x)$ are periodic functions of period $1$.. We have $$f= a_0(x) + a_1 ( x ) x.$$

Now we assume that the statement hold for $n-1$. We consider for $n$. By assumption $$\Delta f= b_0(x) + b_1 ( x ) x +. . . + b_{n-1}(x)x^{n-1}.$$
Note that $$\Delta (f-b_{n-1}(x)x^{n})= c_0(x) + c_1 ( x ) x +. . . + c_{n-2}(x)x^{n-2},$$ where $c_0, c_1, . . . , c_{n-2}$  are periodic functions of period $1$.
By induction, $$f-b_{n-1}(x)x^{n}=a_0(x) + a_1 ( x ) x +. . . + a_{n-1}(x)x^{n-1},$$ where $a_0, a_1, . . . , a_{n-1}$  are periodic functions of period $1$.
Hence the statement holds.

Note that your question can be answered by using theorem for $n-1$ times. Just remember that $\Delta f=0$ is equivalent to $f(x)$ is a periodic function of period $1$ (this is for the first step).